# SQL Connection String in MVC Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Im working on a MVC Application and so far ive been using localDB since that was which was included in the tutorial. I want to switch the application now to my SQL Server but im not sure how to.

I get that I have to change the connection String. But not in what way exactly since the SQL Server has a username and password which my localDB doesnt.

Another question regarding this is, do I have to create the tables myself in the beginning on the SQL Server or will they be generated by the entity framework like in my localDB?

Current connection string for localDB:

```
<add name="AcquisitionDBContext"
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Acquisitions.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Im pretty new to this so any help is very much appreciated

Comment: This is the format: Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to use MS SQL then it wil look something like this:

```
<add name="AcquisitionDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=hostname\sql_instance_name;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Where "hostname\sql_instance_name" is the servername(or ip)/the sql instance name eg. localhost\sqlexpress

Comment: Okay so when I open the sql management studio it shows me:
BLOEK(SQL Server 12.0.2000 - Bloek\Ride) so I guess for me it would be as a datasource "Bloek\Ride". Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how `connection string` should look like (tweak to your needs)

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=server_name,port; Initial Catalog=your_catalogue_name; Integrated Security=False; User ID=userName;Password=Passwd;     MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Before first run I would recommend using `migrations`. 
Go to `PackageManagerConsole` (if you don't have it in menu, install `NuGet` first via `Extension and Updates`)

[image]

Then inside console type `Enable-Migrations` (if you didn't already). 
Next type `Add-Migration your_migration_name` and then `Update-Database` to let `migrations` create tables for you.

If you change something in your model files later, you can again type `Add-Migration your_migration_name` and `Update-Database` to update database with those changes.

Comment: is there a possibility to do this second part in code? I dont have direct access with the visual studio computer to the sql server since its in a different protected network.

Comment: @VIP I've never heard about such possibility

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionStrings.com is the best reference for connection-string syntax. It shows you the options to use when you have a username+password. In this case:

```
Server=myServerAddress; Database=myDataBase; User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;
```

Entity Framework will not create your tables for you unless you tell it to by calling something like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer( new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDbContextHere>() );
```

(Where `Database` is the `System.Data.Entity.Database` type).

Comment: Note: where would I set the Initializer in my application? In the model?

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Just tried this and got the following error:
`{"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."}`

Is that due to the fact that I didnt use the initializer yet?

Comment: @VIP What are the details of the InnerException?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="<<Name of Connection String>>" connectionString="Data Source=<<Put here path to your SQL SErver>>;Initial Catalog=<<Database name>> ;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```